# no translator registered for GroupByKey.GroupByKeyOnly

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Running into this error when trying to do GoGroupByKey using dataflow. At high level, I want to join two PCollection one of type `KV<String, self-defined-class>` and another one of type `KV<String, TableRow>`. I am just doing the standard join by TupleTags, KeyedPCollection and CoGroupByKey very similar to the example listed in [official document](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key#join)

```
    PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>> pt1 = ...;
    PCollection<KV<String, MyClass>> pt2 = ...;
    final TupleTag<TableRow> t1 = new TupleTag<>();
    final TupleTag<MyClass> t2 = new TupleTag<>();
    PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> coGbkResultCollection =
    KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(t1, pt1)
                     .and(t2, pt2)
                     .apply(CoGroupByKey.<String>create());
```

For most, I am sort of confused what it mean (searched around a little bit to found out that it is complaining that does not have a job to "translate" the dataflow "service" query to job but still don't know what it mean technically) and what it is potentially indicating (particular when it is happening GroupByKeyOnly), for which I could just take as hint to debug my code piece.

The entire stacktrace is as follows:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: no translator registered for GroupByKey.GroupByKeyOnly
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator.visitTransform(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:500)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:219)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:215)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:215)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:215)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:102)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:259)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:455)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineTranslator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:146)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.run(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:325)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:95)
```

FYI I am using java library with BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner

EDIT, having poked around the source code I found out that it is because `DataflowPipelineTranslator.java` has not registered Tranformer GroupByKeyOnly in `DataflowPipelineRunner`, so any pipeline running on DataflowPipelineOptions (and any of its extention) will have GroupByKeyOnly registered...?

Comment: Which version of the Dataflow SDK are you using?

Comment: `com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:1.4.0`

Comment: Could you try using the newer 1.5.0 SDK?

Comment: tried, seems not working

Comment: Could you post more of your example here or as a (gist)[https://gist.github.com/]? `CoGroupByKey` works as you're using it -- it is possible that the problem lies elsewhere in your pipeline.

Comment: Are you calling DataflowPipelineRunner.run(Pipeline) or BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(Pipeline)?

Answer (score 1):

GroupByKeyOnly should have never appeared in the set of transforms applied to the graph for the DataflowPipelineRunner and this can happen because the pipeline may have been constructed without the runner being set on PipelineOptions followed by a call to [Blocking]DataflowPipelineRunner.run(Pipeline). The expected pattern is to not use the DataflowPipeline/DataflowPipelineRunner methods directly, for example:

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args);

// Make sure that runner is set before calling Pipeline.create(options)
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

// Apply all your transforms
p.apply(... transforms ...);

PipelineResult result = p.run();
```

With the above example, you will be able to swap runners by adjusting the command line parameters to your application. For example, using the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner will ensure that job result will have reached a terminal state before returning from p.run().